# How to add newly discovered cell node as member of exadata storage server grid in oem12c?

Tags: oracle-enterprise-manager, exadata

I have successfully discovered a new storage node in oem using emcli

```
./emcli add_target -type=oracle_exadata -name="da13cel04.myhost.com" -host="da13db01.myhost.com" -properties="CellName:da13cel04.myhost.com;MgmtIPAddr:10.92.43.23"
Target "da13cel04.myhost.com:oracle_exadata" added successfully
```

But now i want to add this cell node under existing exadata storage grid target in em and i tried below,but it didn't helped

```
./emcli modify_target -type=’oracle_exadata_grid’ -name=’Exadata Grid da13.myhost.com’ -properties=’Members:da13cel01.nyhost.com,da13cel02.myhost.com,da13cel03.myhost.com,da13cel04.myhost.com’
```

Need help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer for my question.Here is the command to add newly discovered cell nodes under existing exadata server grid

```
emcli modify_system -name='Exadata Grid da13.myhost.com' -type='oracle_exadata_grid' -add_members='da13cel04.myhost.com:oracle_exadata'

output:
System "Exadata Grid da13.myhost.com:oracle_exadata_grid" modified successfully
```